# Why is JSON binding inside jQuery template not parsed inside tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-templates

I have an upload script inside an XSL template, which lets JavaScript upload a file. It's inside an XSL template. The upload handler file (upload.php) will return a JSON object when the file is uploaded.

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<a href="${url}">${url}</a>
</script>
```

But when I see the output, only the second `${url}` is parsed.
Propably a JSON binding `${the_binding}` (which is extracted from the JSON object) won't get parsed while it's the value of an attribute.

Thus, the result is the following:

```
<a href="${url}">http://google.com/search?q=this+JSON+binding+is+parsed</a>
```

How to let the binding inside `href` attribute get it's proposed value?

Comment: That looks like a jQuery template, not an XSL template - are you sure you're using XSL?

Comment: If you're using jQuery.tmpl, that should work. It doesn't treat attributes any differently. Can you show us the code you're using to render the template? (e.g. the `$('#template-download').tmpl()` bit)

Comment: It's a<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

Comment: Ok. But what's that got to do with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an example of that template being rendered correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/skilldrick/v8cww/):

```
$('#template-download').tmpl({url: 'http://google.com'}).appendTo('body');
```

If that's not working for you, then there must be something wrong in how you're rendering the template.